# How to update "nothing" in ajax events?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an ajax event triggered via some events in Primefaces JSF components.
I want this event to only process the values of the specific field that contains this event, but not to update anything, only process. Something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update="@none"/>
```

Is something like this possible to do?

Comment: Go ahead and try it, `@none` is a valid keyword to specify that nothing is to be updated.

Comment: It's by the way already the default value. So you can also just omit the `update` attribute altogether.

Comment: and for the "process" attribute, what is the default selector?

Comment: @MateusViccari Default value of `process` is `@this`, see [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/ajax.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `@none` is a valid keyword to say that nothing will be updated.

There is standard keywords which can be used in JSF2 in [the `render` attribute](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html):

> If a literal is specified the identifiers must be space delimited. Any
>   of the keywords "@this", "@form", "@all", "@none" may be specified in
>   the identifier list.

PrimeFaces uses the `update` attribute for the same purpose with the almost the sames values.

- [Partial tree processing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf)

Comment: Oh thank you, i saw that page once but i could not find it again.